# How to recognize a symmetrical circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, differential, transfer-function

I'm reading a book (Vatché Vorperian's book on the extra element theorem) and there is a problem which states :
[image]

I found solving this problem interesting. However, the hint is most useful for other circuits. Because if the circuit is so called 'symmetrical', then nulling either v1 or v2 and solving for the gain vo/v2 or vo/v1 (respectively) allows to the  deduce the differential gain easily.

My question is:
How can we determine accurately that a circuit is symmetrical? The hint given in the problem makes it look like it's only a formality to determine if the circuit is symmetrical. But if we didn't know yet the transfer function (if in fact it wasn't given to be proven), then how could I determine that yes, this circuit is symmetrical?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no substitute for working it out without flaky assumptions.